# Delete all files and history from remote Git repo without deleting repo itself

Tags: git

I would appreciate it if someone could tell me how I could delete every single file/folder on my git repository without actually deleting the repository itself. I want to delete all history associated with those files as well.

Comment: Your title says that you're talking about cleaning out a "remote git repo" and you've tagged this question "github", so are you trying to reduce the amount of space that you are using on github?  Or are you talking about another remote repository?  A few more details would be helpful here.

Comment: I would like to 'delete every single file/folder on my git repo without actually deleting the repo itself.'. I am talking about my github repository.

Comment: delete with history or keep history intact?

Comment: then ceilingfish's answer is correct (delete branches and tags). why do you want to do that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can delete a branch from a repository remote like this

```
git push origin :branchname
```

if you've got any tags you can delete them like this:

```
git push origin :refs/tags/tagname
```

This is assuming you have a remote set up to github called origin

This will leave the local tags / branches on your computer, though.

Comment: it will not allow me to delete the master branch. Is there a way where I can just delete all the files within it?

Comment: You could create an empty branch locally (`git branch cleanerbranch`, delete all the files in it, then commit that), then push that to the remote `git push origin cleanerbranch:master`).

Comment: That would still have the history, though, assuming `git branch cleanerbranch` was run while on `master`.  The OP would have to do something like [GitHub's advice for creating a `gh-pages` branch at a new, empty, root commit](http://pages.github.com/#project_pages) and then `git push -f origin gh-pages:master`

Comment: @Mark: Or just create a new repository, with an initial commit of whatever it is you want (including nothing, if desired), and push that repo's master branch. Done.

Comment: @Jefromi: yes, much easier :)

Comment: @Jefromi - I did not get it. How? I have to add remote first? How to I push?

Comment: @Jefromi `git push origin --mirror` is also particularly effective, as explain in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5363857/delete-all-files-and-history-from-remote-git-repo-without-deleting-repo-itself/18177448#18177448).

Comment: Does not work `! [remote rejected] master (refusing to delete the current branch: refs/heads/master)`

Answer (score 80):

As I explain in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18112966/how-to-delete-purge-remove-all-history-commits-references-branches-from-a-remote/18113182#18113182) to [Delete or remove all history, commits, and branches from a remote Git repo?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18112966/456814), you can also achieve the same thing as [Ceilingfish's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5363857/clean-out-remote-git-repo-delete-all-files-but-not-the-repo-itself/5363971#5363971) (i.e. delete all references/branches/tags in the remote repo) by doing the following:

1. Create new empty repo with initial commit:

   ```
   mkdir new
   cd new
   echo "This is the README" > README.md
   git init
   git add .
   git commit -m "Add README.md (initial commit)"
   ```
2. Add remote repo as origin:

   ```
   git remote add origin <url-to-remote>
   ```
3. Mirror push to remote:

   ```
   git push origin --mirror
   ```

That will ***delete all references/branches/tags in your remote repo***, and any dangling commits will probably be garbage collected eventually. From the [official Linux Kernel Git documentation for `git push`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-push.html) (emphasis mine):

> ```
> --mirror
> ```
>
> Instead of naming each ref to push, specifies that all refs under `refs/` (which includes but is not limited to `refs/heads/`, `refs/remotes/`, and `refs/tags/`) be mirrored to the remote repository. Newly created local refs will be pushed to the remote end, locally updated refs will be force updated on the remote end, and ***deleted refs will be removed from the remote end***.

Answer (score 4):

This is what I have done

> git rm -r -f -q
>
> git commit
>
> git push

Then you have to manually delete the files,  git rm remove the files from the repo but not from the file system

Comment: This does not delete git history!

Answer (score 1):

## Simple solution

1. Create an empty repo with `git init` in a new dir.
2. `git remote add origin <url-to-remote>`
3. **If the remote server is github**: `git checkout -b main`
4. `git push origin --mirror`