# How to delete everything inside GIT repository?

Tags: git, github

How can I delete everything from GIT repository, so that no one can see any history?

If you ask why I want to do that. For security reasons, I need to protect the code into another server.

Comment: probably something along the lines of going to the first commit, amending it to put nothing in it, then push --force.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18112966/how-to-delete-purge-remove-all-history-commits-references-branches-from-a-remote (How to delete/purge/remove all history/commits/references/branches from a remote Git repo?)

Comment: Could someone give me detailed steps? Sorry, I'm new to GIT.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to delete/purge/remove all history/commits/references/branches from a remote Git repo?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18112966/how-to-delete-purge-remove-all-history-commits-references-branches-from-a-remote), and [Delete all files and history from remote Git repo without deleting repo itself](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5363857/456814).

Comment: Note that if you're doing this for **security** reasons, e.g. removing sensitive data, then all of that data will **still exist** on the remote repo as dangling commits, until garbage collection is run on the remote repo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**THIS WILL DELETE ALL COMMITS AND HISTORY IN YOUR REMOTE REPOSITORY.  MAKE SURE THIS IS WHAT YOU WANT TO DO BEFORE CONTINUING.**

1. Create a new, empty directory
2. In this directory, `git init`
3. `git remote add origin remote-url` (replace remote-url with the remote repo you will be deleting)
4. Need to create an initial commit so: `touch .empty`
5. `git add .empty`
6. `git commit`
7. `git push origin --mirror`

If anyone clones your remote repository, they will clone a tiny repository that only contains `.empty`.  Note that while your git refs will be unreachable from any commit, they still exist on the server until `git gc` is run on the server end.  If you're hosting with GitHub or BitBucket, this is done periodically.  But, if that's the case, just delete the repository.

Comment: Note that if the original poster is doing this for **security** reasons, e.g. removing sensitive data, then all of that data will **still exist** on the remote repo as dangling commits, until garbage collection is run on the remote repo.