# Git repository clean up

Tags: git, repository, bitbucket

So I have this huge bitbucket repository with so many branches, each with tens of commits some of which are really small. Now that the entire thing works perfectly, I want a clean repo with only the final commits and required branches. How do I achieve a 'repository clean-up' where I can remove the unnecessary branches and the commits and have a final clean repo?

Please help me out.

Comment: https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Answers-Developer-Questions/Is-there-a-way-to-delete-branches-in-bulk/qaq-p/547331

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the solution [here](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Answers-Developer-Questions/Is-there-a-way-to-delete-branches-in-bulk/qaq-p/547331):

```
# Make sure remotes are up to date (with stale remotes purged):
git fetch -p

# Initial no-op run --- do the branches to delete look correct?
# Be careful to omit 'master' from the output.
git branch --remote --merged origin/master | grep -v 'master' | cut -b 10- | xargs

# Do the bulk delete!!!  (can take a long time...)
git branch --remote --merged origin/master | grep -v 'master' | cut -b 10- | xargs git push --delete origin
```

This will delete branches that have been merged into a 'master' branch. You can modify to reflect whatever organization your repo is using.

Answer (score 0):

1. first clone the final commit from your bitbucket repo in your pc. for this please see this post: https://coderwall.com/p/xyuoza/git-cloning-specific-commits
2. then clean full repository without deleting repo itself. for this please see the this post: [Delete all files and history from remote Git repo without deleting repo itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5363857/delete-all-files-and-history-from-remote-git-repo-without-deleting-repo-itself)
3. then again push the final copy(that copy you cloning from git repo earlier) to your desire bitbucket repository.

I'm sorry if i wrote something unapproprite here. I'm novice. So please don't mind.
I don't know if you want the solution like this or not!
if not then I'm sorry again.

Comment: I have more than one branch that I want to retain, is it possible through this method? Can I clone the most recent commits of multiple branches and delete the complete repo and push them again to the respective branches so that they only have a single final commit?